# How do I write to a matrix without repeating the header in R? I just want to output one header with the other rows

Tags: r

How do I write to a matrix without repeating the header in R?  I just want to output one header with the other rows

Code:

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(asset_returns_xts)) {
    a <- sweep(asset_returns_xts[i,], 2, colSums(asset_returns_xts), "/")
    print(a)
}
            

  SPY       EFA       IWM          EEM        AGG
2021-02-17 -0.0170188 0.5615421 0.8752446 -0.009493439 -0.4182321
                 SPY       EFA      IWM       EEM       AGG
2021-02-18 0.3156288 0.4769932 1.729427 0.3796061 0.1088958
                 SPY        EFA       IWM        EEM       AGG
2021-02-19 0.1309662 -0.2775318 -2.328678 -0.1780247 0.6536597
                 SPY       EFA       IWM       EEM       AGG
2021-02-22 0.5704238 0.2389965 0.7240063 0.8079121 0.6556765
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `print` statement that ensures the column names are outputted. Since you want to print the complete matrix, could we gain our results differently? Yes

Instead of printing the resulting row, we can gather them throughout the iterations.

```
results <- list()
for ( i in 1:nrow(asset_returns_xts)) {
    a <- sweep(asset_returns_xts[i,], 2, colSums(asset_returns_xts), "/")
    results[[i]] <- a
    print(a)
}
print(do.call(rbind, results))
```

The reason I am using a list, is that in a naïve approach where you would repeatedly `rbind` the results, is that for each iteration you are copying all the rows of the previous result, adding the extra line, and replacing the result with the new combined matrix. For each added row, you are repeatedly copying more and more rows.

R doesn't copy the contents of list, when you assign something to its entries.

Comment: ++++Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I tried searching and various code but nothing worked.

Comment: But does the actual matrix/array ("results" or "a") have the header on each row?  I may want to perform further calculations on the matrix/array.  See below when I print(results).  Thanks

Comment: > print(results)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
                 SPY       EFA      IWM       EEM        AGG
2021-02-18 -18.54589 0.8494344 1.975936 -39.98615 -0.2603718

[[3]]
                 SPY       EFA       IWM        EEM      AGG
2021-02-19 0.4149374 -0.581836 -1.346503 -0.4689724 6.002615

[[4]]
                SPY        EFA        IWM       EEM      AGG
2021-02-22 4.355505 -0.8611497 -0.3109088 -4.538201 1.003085

Comment: Try looking at what `do.call(rbind, results)` returns. But short answer, no.